# A* search with resources and locks

Tags: c++

Consider a path optimization problem with resources and locks. We are given a weighted undirected graph, and the goal is to travel as cheaply as possible from a given start vertex to a given goal vertex. Here the problem is that some of the vertices are blocked, can have a view of the problem hereand can only be unblocked if the agent is carrying an appropriate resource (key), which can be found in other vertices of the graph (which may also be blocked or not).

**Implement using A* search that picks the move with best immediate heuristic value.**

i have tried many codes on a* search. But i don't understand how to write it with keys and resources.Can you help me out?

The below is the code for a* search that i have tried. But there are no locks and keys included in that.I need help to code including locks and keys.

```
void aStarSearch(int grid[][COL], Pair src, Pair dest)
{
    // If the source is out of range
    if (isValid (src.first, src.second) == false)
    {
        printf ("Source is invalid\n");
        return;
    }

    // If the destination is out of range
    if (isValid (dest.first, dest.second) == false)
    {
        printf ("Destination is invalid\n");
        return;
    }

    // Either the source or the destination is blocked
    if (isUnBlocked(grid, src.first, src.second) == false ||
            isUnBlocked(grid, dest.first, dest.second) == false)
    {
        printf ("Source or the destination is blocked\n");
        return;
    }

    // If the destination cell is the same as source cell
    if (isDestination(src.first, src.second, dest) == true)
    {
        printf ("We are already at the destination\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create a closed list and initialise it to false which means
    // that no cell has been included yet
    // This closed list is implemented as a boolean 2D array
    bool closedList[ROW][COL];
    memset(closedList, false, sizeof (closedList));

    // Declare a 2D array of structure to hold the details
    //of that cell
    cell cellDetails[ROW][COL];

    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<ROW; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<COL; j++)
        {
            cellDetails[i][j].f = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].g = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].h = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].parent_i = -1;
            cellDetails[i][j].parent_j = -1;
        }
    }

    // Initialising the parameters of the starting node
    i = src.first, j = src.second;
    cellDetails[i][j].f = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].g = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].h = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].parent_i = i;
    cellDetails[i][j].parent_j = j;

    /*
     Create an open list having information as-
     <f, <i, j>>
     where f = g + h,
     and i, j are the row and column index of that cell
     Note that 0 <= i <= ROW-1 & 0 <= j <= COL-1
     This open list is implenented as a set of pair of pair.*/
    set<pPair> openList;

    // Put the starting cell on the open list and set its
    // 'f' as 0
    openList.insert(make_pair (0.0, make_pair (i, j)));

    // We set this boolean value as false as initially
    // the destination is not reached.
    bool foundDest = false;

    while (!openList.empty())
    {
        pPair p = *openList.begin();

        // Remove this vertex from the open list
        openList.erase(openList.begin());

        // Add this vertex to the closed list
        i = p.second.first;
        j = p.second.second;
        closedList[i][j] = true;

       /*
        Generating all the 8 successor of this cell

            N.W   N   N.E
              \   |   /
               \  |  /
            W----Cell----E
                 / | \
               /   |  \
            S.W    S   S.E

        Cell-->Popped Cell (i, j)
        N -->  North       (i-1, j)
        S -->  South       (i+1, j)
        E -->  East        (i, j+1)
        W -->  West           (i, j-1)
        N.E--> North-East  (i-1, j+1)
        N.W--> North-West  (i-1, j-1)
        S.E--> South-East  (i+1, j+1)
        S.W--> South-West  (i+1, j-1)*/

        // To store the 'g', 'h' and 'f' of the 8 successors
        double gNew, hNew, fNew;

        //----------- 1st Successor (North) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i-1, j) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i-1, j, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }
            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i-1][j] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked(grid, i-1, j) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue (i-1, j, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i-1][j].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i-1][j].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair(fNew,
                                               make_pair(i-1, j)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 2nd Successor (South) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i+1, j) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i+1, j, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }
            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i+1][j] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked(grid, i+1, j) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i+1, j, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i+1][j].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i+1][j].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew, make_pair (i+1, j)));
                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 3rd Successor (East) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid (i, j+1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i, j+1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i][j+1] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked (grid, i, j+1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue (i, j+1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i][j+1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i][j+1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair(fNew,
                                        make_pair (i, j+1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 4th Successor (West) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i, j-1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i, j-1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i][j-1] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked(grid, i, j-1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i, j-1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i][j-1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i][j-1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew,
                                          make_pair (i, j-1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 5th Successor (North-East) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i-1, j+1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i-1, j+1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i-1][j+1] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked(grid, i-1, j+1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i-1, j+1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i-1][j+1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i-1][j+1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew, 
                                    make_pair(i-1, j+1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 6th Successor (North-West) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid (i-1, j-1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination (i-1, j-1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i-1][j-1] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked(grid, i-1, j-1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i-1, j-1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i-1][j-1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i-1][j-1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew, make_pair (i-1, j-1)));
                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 7th Successor (South-East) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i+1, j+1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i+1, j+1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i+1][j+1] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked(grid, i+1, j+1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i+1, j+1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i+1][j+1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i+1][j+1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert(make_pair(fNew, 
                                        make_pair (i+1, j+1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 8th Successor (South-West) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid (i+1, j-1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i+1, j-1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i+1][j-1] == false &&
                     isUnBlocked(grid, i+1, j-1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i+1, j-1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //                OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i+1][j-1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i+1][j-1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert(make_pair(fNew, 
                                        make_pair(i+1, j-1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // When the destination cell is not found and the open
    // list is empty, then we conclude that we failed to
    // reach the destiantion cell. This may happen when the
    // there is no way to destination cell (due to blockages)
    if (foundDest == false)
        printf("Failed to find the Destination Cell\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us what you've tried, and where you are stuck. See [ask] for more information. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You have to get the keys before the locks. You can remember the positions of the locks (or rather the identifier of the locks). This should be enough to put you onto the path.

Comment: @rsjaffe Your comment is a little messed up. If you auto'd it, could you post a bug report on meta?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I did auto it, but it looks ok to me. Could you quote the section that looks odd? Thanks.

Comment: @rsjaffe Welcome to Where Developers Learn...

Comment: @mavella It looks like it'd be a good idea to put your nth successor code into a separate function.

Comment: This code appears to be copied from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: This code suffers from an abundance of copy-pasting. (geeksforgeeks is not a good source of knowledge.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution (not sure if best) is this:

You have an original graph G where edges can be locked to K possible keys. You can generate a new graph G' by layering 2^K copies of graph G, one for each combination of keys, but changed so that edges either exist or not, according to the keys represented by the layer. (For example, imagine a graph with two corridors, one with blue lock one with red; K=2, so we need to make 4 layers: no-key layer, blue layer, red layer, and all-key layer. In the no-key layer, both corridors' edges would not exist; in all-key layer, they both do; in the blue and red layer, only the respective edge exists, while the other does not.)

This effectively transforms the search states from (position) to (position, inventory), in order to remember what you are carrying. (For example, instead of states like "boiler room", now you have states like "boiler room while carrying the red key".)

Then, you can connect the layers at the locations where the keys are found. You can use a directed edge if a key cannot be dropped, or a bidi edge if a key can be dropped or you can't be bothered making a bidi graph. This way, every time a key is found, you "jump up" to the layer that has all the current keys, plus the newly found one. (For example, in the room with the red key, make an edge from the no-key graph's room node to the red graph's one, and from blue graph's to all-key one.)

Finally, make all the copies of the destination node as final. Or equivalently, make a zero-cost edge from all copies of the destination node to the original no-key layer's destination node.

If you need to spend a key to unlock a door, as opposed to just have it in your possession, you can change the door edges to drop you down to the layer where you have all keys except the one corresponding to the door.

If you can carry only one key at a time, you don't need 2^K copies of G; mere K+1 layers suffice (no-key, red, blue). Change edges accordingly.

Obviously, this baloons the search space by the factor of 2^K, but there is virtually no change to the search algorithm, only to the graph itself.

This doesn't work any more if you can drop keys at arbitrary locations and expect to find them there again. (It will still work if you can drop keys and find them at their original spawn points.)

Comment: We can create a abstract graph with only lock and key vertex to reduce graph size. so we have way point for true path where we can reuse A*.

Comment: @Jarod42: You mean, find distances/paths between all the "important" places, reduce the graph to just those vertices, then employ the layering I described on just this reduced graph? I like it. (I also just noticed it's not edges that are blocked, but vertices. Not much changes in my approach, just take out the whole vertex along with its edges in the layers without the appropriate key.)

Comment: It is what I mean by the abstract graph. but we can have both blocked vertices/edges: door is mostly edge (other path may allow to be on each side of the door), trap room (with lasers, or other dying stuff) would be vertex. (but blocked vertex can mostly be simulated by blocking all incoming edges).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. And a vertex with no edges might as well not be there (unless you're stuck in it).